# Are ASP.NET cookies checked in the server's side?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, authentication

My ASP.NET project uses the default authentication scheme out of the box. Basically I have a Controller like below that shows sensitive information about users

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,Faculty")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoadMemberTable(int max = 20)
{
    var usersAdded = await _mongoDbContext.Members.Where(x => x.EncoderId == "0").ToListAsync();

    return PartialView("Faculty/StudentTable", usersAdded);
}
```

So as you can see the endpoint requires the roles Administrator or Faculty, will a bad actor be able to edit his own cookie and let's say forge that his role is an Administrator? Even if he was able to log in with a normal user account with no roles, will he be able to access this endpoint via editing his cookies? Or does ASP.NET Core check this cookie every request? And lastly, do I have to implement my own checks in the endpoint? Like checking if the user really has the role of Administrator or Faculty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, After user sign in, Asp.Net Core will create an encrypted cookie and adds it to the current response, It's very difficult for a bad actor to edit this cookie.

ASP.NET Core checks the authentication cookie on every request automatically,

Because you add `[Authorize(Roles = "xxx,xxx")]` to the endpoint. The authentication middleware verifies the user's identity and roles based on the information stored in the authentication cookie automatically, You don't need to write code to verify this by yourself.